# how to read this sql server query when it consists of multiple functions used to get the output. Please expalin it in brief?

Tags: sql-server

I'm unable to decode this query because it consists of multiple functions.
Please explain it in brief.
Also please let me know how to understand the query when multiple functions were used in a query.?

**Question**:

```
declare @date varchar(200)

set @date='Choice: 820P-EDI Report bulk printing,
Choice: Cash-cash, Choice: CCSh-CHAIN STORE CASH, CHOICE: coll-collection,
choice: cred-credit, choice: RSH-cash resolution'
```

**Answer**:

```
select upper(concat(left(stuff(@date,1,charindex(':',@date),''),5),',',
left(stuff(@date,1,charindex(':',@date,charindex(':',@date)+1),''),5),',',left(stuff(stuff(@date,1,charindex(',',@date,charindex(',',@date)+1),''),1,
charindex(':',stuff(@date,1,charindex(',',@date,charindex(',',@date)+1),'')),''),5),',',reverse(left(stuff(stuff(reverse(@date),1,charindex(',',reverse(@date),charindex(',',reverse(@date))+1),''),
1,charindex('-',stuff(reverse(@date),1,charindex(',',reverse(@date),charindex(',',reverse(@date))+1),'')),''),5)),',',left(reverse(substring(stuff(reverse(@date),1,charindex(',',reverse(@date)),''),1
,charindex(':',stuff(reverse(@date),1,charindex(',',reverse(@date)),''))-1)),5),',',left(reverse(substring(reverse(@date),1,charindex(':',reverse(@date))-1)),4)))
```

**Output**:

```
820P, CASH, CCSH, COLL, CRED, RSH
```

Comment: If you format the query, things should become much clearer. Looks like a lot of string manipulation, which is never easy to read in sql.

Comment: The goal is to extract the strings delimited by "Choice: " (front) and "-" (end). IMO a string splitter function implementing this specific logic used with a string aggregation method would be a far better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A little formatting goes a long way in these instances.

```
SELECT  UPPER(
            CONCAT(
                LEFT(STUFF(@date, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @date), ''), 5)
            ,   ','
            ,   LEFT(STUFF(@date, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @date, CHARINDEX(':', @date) + 1), ''), 5)
            ,   ','
            ,   LEFT(STUFF(
                         STUFF(@date, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @date, CHARINDEX(',', @date) + 1), '')
                     ,   1
                     ,   CHARINDEX(':', STUFF(@date, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @date, CHARINDEX(',', @date) + 1), ''))
                     ,   ''), 5)
            ,   ','
            ,   REVERSE(
                    LEFT(STUFF(
                             STUFF(REVERSE(@date), 1, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@date), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@date)) + 1), '')
                         ,   1
                         ,   CHARINDEX('-', STUFF(REVERSE(@date), 1, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@date), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@date)) + 1), ''))
                         ,   ''), 5))
            ,   ','
            ,   LEFT(REVERSE(
                         SUBSTRING(
                             STUFF(REVERSE(@date), 1, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@date)), '')
                         ,   1
                         ,   CHARINDEX(':', STUFF(REVERSE(@date), 1, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@date)), '')) - 1)), 5)
            ,   ','
            ,   LEFT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@date), 1, CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@date)) - 1)), 4)));
```

Just breaking it down into the individual components helps.  "The only way to eat an elephant is one bite at a time."